# How to locate framework api with high cpu usage for php-fpm

Tags: php, laravel

I'm optimising for some slow, high-occupancy api using the laravel and thinkphp framework
The slow-logging api in php-fpm have all been migrated to separate containers, but there are still some local php-fpm processes that are suddenly taking up a lot of cpu.
However, there are still some php-fpm processes on the local machine that are suddenly taking up a lot of cpu, is there any tool or solution that can locate which interface these processes are requesting?

I confirm that opcache is enabled

So I'm looking for a tool or a solution that can meet the requirements

I've looked at xhgui, but it seems to only return memory usage and cpu usage time.

Comment: New Relic should help you. https://newrelic.com/

Comment: Please review what is on topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to recommend an off-site resource, like a tool, are explicitly _off topic_ as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.